# Is the homeomorphism class of a connected open set of C determined by its fundamental group? 

Tags: cv.complex-variables, at.algebraic-topology, tag-removed

Let $U,U'\subseteq\mathbf{C}$ be two connected open sets such that $\pi_1(U)\simeq\pi_1(U')$.

Q: Does this imply that $U$ is homeomorphic to $U'$?

In the case where the $\pi_1$'s are trivial then the answer is yes, this is a consequence of 
Riemann's mapping theorem. May be one should try to prove it when the $\pi_1$'s are free
groups on $n$ generators...

Comment: The answer is no.  Let $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a cantor set, and $z$ some point not in $K$, then $U=\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ and $U^{\prime}=\mathbb{C}\setminus (K\cup z)$ are not homeomorphic (if I understand the classification of noncompact surfaces correctly.)  However, both have $\pi_{1}$ equal to an infinite free group.

Comment: This seems to be a nice example. Then probably one should impose some "finiteness" conditions on the $\pi_1$'s in order (to have a chance)
for the statement to be true.  

Comment: If $\pi_1$ is finitely generated, then it is true. For example, U is conformally equivalent to a circle domain (Koebes's theorem), and two such domains with the same $\pi_1$ are easily seen to be homeomorphic.

Comment: Hi @Maxime! This sounds already like a nice theorem.

Comment: David Cohen : I don't think the two domains you gave have the same $\pi_1$... For example, every loop in $\mathbb{C} \setminus K$ goes around infinitely many points of $K$ since the latter has no isolated points.

Comment: David's counterexample is correct. Every open subset of the plane has free fundamental group with at most countably many generators. 

Comment: @EtienneMatheron : The unit disk *is* homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, for example via $f(z)=z/(1-|z|^2)$. These sets are not conformally equivalent, though.

Comment: Of Course! I had indeed in mind ``conformally equivalent".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is indeed no as David Cohen has pointed out, and more generally the answer is determined by the complements of the sets U and U'.

The complete solution is effectively due to R.L. Moore (1925), the key fact being every nondegenerate monotone upper semicontinuous decomposition of the 2-sphere yields a 2-sphere.

Thus to decide if two open connected planar sets U and U' are homeomorphic, let C and C' denote the respective complements of U and U' in the extended plane.

Now take the respective topological quotients K and K' of C and C', collapsing each component of C or C' to a point. Then U and U' are homeomorphic iff K and K' are homeomorphic.

Comment: 
To fill in a few details in the above, suppose K and K' are nonempty compact totally disconnected subsets of the 2-sphere, with respective complements U and U'. Then any homeomorphism between U and U' extends to a homeomorphism of the 2-sphere, and any homeomorphism between K and K' extends to a homeomorphism of the 2-sphere. For the latter direction, see the pf. in Van Mill's book on infinitely dimensional topology that the Cantor set cannot be wildly embedded in the plane. For the former direction apply the Schoenflies theorem repeatedly.